# Collapsible dynamic BOM via jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, css, sql-server

I have a php page pulling data from a sql2000 stored procedure representing the BOM (Bill of Material) for a product. Right now it's displaying as a flat table, and works great. However, after 3 days of googling/hacking, I can't for the life of me figure out how tranform that data into an indented collapsable/expandable table or UL.

Table is as follows:

- ID[<--unique]
- BOM_Level
- Parent_Item
- Component_Item
- Component_qty

The BOM_Level is exactly that, the level of the BOM (a number between 0-12). I was assuming because that was provided it would be simple, in that the bom_level really represents the level of indentation of each part, but alas, it has not been simple....

The general structure is as follows, but the number of parts and levels will vary by product:

```
0 Top Level
 1 - Assembly 1
  2 - part 1 of Assembly 1
  2 - part 2 of Assembly 1
  2 - part 3 of Assembly 1
  2 - part 4 of Assembly 1
 1 - Assembly 2
  2 - Assembly 1 of Assembly 2
   3 - part 1 of Assembly 1 of Assembly 2
   3 - part 2 of Assembly 1 of Assembly 2
   3 - part 3 of Assembly 1 of Assembly 2
```

I've been trying to do something like:

- If the bom_level is == previous_bom_level then create li
- If the bom_level is > previous_bom_level add a new UL and start new li
- If the BOM level is < previous bom level, wrap up the previous UL and start another set of li.

With all that being said, I just can't quite wrap my head around how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I get the feeling BOM here doesn't stand for Browser Object Model...

Comment: Good point! Updated question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have data like this:

```
// plus any additional data per entry
$data = array (
  array (
    'id' => '10',
    'bom_level' => '2',
    'parent_item_no' => '2800CF',
    'comp_item_no' => '2800CF-02',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '66',
    'bom_level' => '3',
    'parent_item_no' => '2800CF-02',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-12',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '189',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-12',
    'comp_item_no' => '0578',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '190',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-12',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-SH11',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '222',
    'bom_level' => '5',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-SH11',
    'comp_item_no' => '1000',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '191',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-12',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-SH12',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '223',
    'bom_level' => '5',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-SH12',
    'comp_item_no' => '1000',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '67',
    'bom_level' => '3',
    'parent_item_no' => '2800CF-02',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-AG01',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '192',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-AG01',
    'comp_item_no' => '303025-20',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '68',
    'bom_level' => '3',
    'parent_item_no' => '2800CF-02',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-PL13',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '193',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-PL13',
    'comp_item_no' => '0500',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '69',
    'bom_level' => '3',
    'parent_item_no' => '2800CF-02',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-PL14',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '194',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-PL14',
    'comp_item_no' => '0187',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '70',
    'bom_level' => '3',
    'parent_item_no' => '2800CF-02',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-SQ01',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '195',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-SQ01',
    'comp_item_no' => '050018-20',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '71',
    'bom_level' => '3',
    'parent_item_no' => '2800CF-02',
    'comp_item_no' => '2000CF-WB06',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '196',
    'bom_level' => '4',
    'parent_item_no' => '2000CF-WB06',
    'comp_item_no' => '040013-20',
  ),
);
```

Where `comp_item_no` is unique, and `parent_item_no` points to it's parent. With `parent_item_no=0` being a root node.

You can map this to another structure with:

```
$map = array();
foreach ($data as $entry) {
  if (!isset($map[$entry['parent_item_no']])) {
    $map[$entry['parent_item_no']] = array();
  }

  $map[$entry['parent_item_no']][] = $entry;
}
```

Which in turn can be recursively traversed, with something like this:

```
function helper($children, $map) {
  if (sizeof($children) > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($children as $parentId => $child) {
      echo '<li>';
      echo $child['comp_item_no'];
      if ($child['comp_item_no'] !== $child['parent_item_no'] && isset($map[$child['comp_item_no']])) {
        helper($map[$child['comp_item_no']], $map);
      }
      echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}

/**
 * note that '2800CF' here is manually choosen
 * because it has the lowest bom_level! In your real
 * code you might want to capture those nodes while
 * restructuring the array (see above)
 */
helper($map['2800CF'], $map);
```

to produce a nested ul. Example (for the data from above):

> - 2800CF-02
>
>   - 2000CF-12
>
>     - 0578
>     - 2000CF-SH11
>
>       - 1000
>     - 2000CF-SH12
>
>       - 1000
>   - 2000CF-AG01
>
>     - 303025-20
>   - 2000CF-PL13
>
>     - 0500
>   - 2000CF-PL14
>
>     - 0187
>   - 2000CF-SQ01
>
>     - 050018-20
>   - 2000CF-WB06
>
>     - 040013-20

Demo: http://codepad.org/FJwX3Z1c

Comment: When you say "parent points to it's parent's" do you mean that parent point to it's parent's ID? If that the case (which I think it is) I'm not sure how to extrapolate that from the table, as the "parent_ID" isn't available. Only Parent_Item_no (which is the part number). I'm sure it's possible, I just don't know how to do it. I was trying something like this, but with no avail:

if($parent_item_no == $oldparent_item_no){$parentid = $oldid;} else {$parentid = $id; $oldid = $id;}

Comment: I should have added some details: I'm trying to loop through the results of the CALL, and feed that data into an array which matches the data structure you provided in your example array(id, parentid, component_item_no). The line of code above is in the loops, trying to infer the parentid by comparing the parent_item_number to the previous parent_item_no.

Comment: Yes, I meant `parent` to be the ID of the actual parent. Maybe you can add some of the data you're actual working with (maybe use var_export or something), so I can adapt the example code.

Comment: From what you're writing (`"parent_ID" isn't available. Only Parent_Item_no (which is the part number)`) I would guess, that you could just change `parent` with `Parent_Item_no` and `id` with the item no. The only thing required is, that what ever you choose to be the id of an entry, it has to be unique.

Comment: thanks for your help so far: Here's a sample of what the table looks like: http://codepad.org/xZ2VLAH5

Comment: I know this is my fault and that what you're saying is the right answer, but something isn't clicking for me. I'm loading the data into the array like this: $data[] = array('id'=>$id, 'bom_level'=>$bom_level, 'parent_item_no'=>$parent_item_no, 'comp_item_no'=>$comp_item_no); is that not the right way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4037/discussion-between-edward-and-yoshi)